# Внедрить share-кнопки социальных сетей?

Tags: javascript, html, соцсети

Нужно внедрить возможность через сайт публикацию в соц сетях.
Попробовал, к примеру, в вк следующее:

```
        url  = 'http://vk.com/share.php?';
        url += 'url='          + encodeURIComponent('mysite.com');
        url += '&title='       + encodeURIComponent('title');
        url += '&description=' + encodeURIComponent('description');
        url += '&noparse=true';
        window.open(url,'','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

Но столкнулся с тем, что из поля **description** раздел комментария поста (в попапе) не заполняется. 
Плюс ко всему, в самом попапе не работает кнопка **рассказать друзьям на странице**, но работает тот момент, если отправить запись личным сообщением.

Пробовал вариант из доки вк, проблемы идентичны:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/share.js?93" charset="windows-1251"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
document.write(VK.Share.button({
  url: 'http://mysite.com',
  title: 'Заголовок страницы',
  description: 'Это мой собственный сайт, я его очень долго делал',
  image: 'http://mysite.com/mypic.jpg',
  noparse: true
}));
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь готовый базовый шаблон шэринга в соц сетях (не скачивая пакеты в npm)?

Мне надо бы vk, fb, twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Какое-то время пользовался http://share42.com/ru

Быстро и удобно.

натыкали иконок каких надо, загрузили скрипт, воткнули код ниже (или подобный для cms, там все на странице есть), и ура. :)

Так же там множество настроект, для дескрипшина и остального. Туда можно натыкать переменные.

```
<div class="share42init"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.name/share42/share42.js"></script>
```